# Would time dilation affect temperature?

Tags: temperature, time-dilation

[This answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/26439) on Astronomy.SE got me thinking about temperature, and our definition of it. The answer is to a question about why the temperature of a black hole is so cold when it absorbs so much energy, and implies that, due to gravitational time dilation, everything is moving slow so from our perspective the temperature of a black hole is for all intents and purposes absolute zero since the particles aren't moving.

In a hypothetical scenario where I can slow time down inside of a bubble, would observations from outside the bubble interpret the temperature inside the bubble as having dropped? Conversely, would that mean that if observers inside the bubble can see outside of it, the temperature outside the bubble would suddenly appear hotter to them?

If so, is this just some form of phantom effect where two observers inside and out don't agree on the absolute temperature reading, but neither one winds up frozen or burnt to a crisp?

Comment: *"our definition of [temperature]"* As Zemansky & Dittman say *'The concept of temperature is rich in interpretations and levels of abstraction.''* If you are trying to reason about black holes in terms of a definition of temperature from kinetic theory you're working on the wrong level of abstraction. But I'm a bit out of my depth on the matter and want to leave it to an expert to provide an answer.

Comment: @dmckee Ok, I guess what I really want to know is does it even make any sense at all to say that a black hole is "cold" if what you observe the temperature to be could be different if looking on the outside vs in.